# Error: Object doesn't support this property or method working in chrome not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

When i am trying to move elements from listA to List B , getting  "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method" but working fine in chrome. Getting error at bold line.

```
function moveAllRight()
{
var left = document.getElementById('listA');
var right = document.getElementById('listB');

var i=left.options.length;
    if(i>0){
        while(i >=0){
            right[i]=left[i]; // <-- error
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you moving options from one select to another?

Comment: In which line does that error message tell you? Are you sure it's from this script?

Comment: getting error for the line right[i]=left[i];

Comment: You are using direct assignment to a DOM property that is likely read only. Instead use `right.appendChild(left[i])` .

Answer (score 2):

It appears `left` and `right` are `<select>` elements. If Internet Explorer doesn't allow you set options this way, then you should use the standard DOM API to add and remove the properties.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).

You could do:

```
// Remove existing options
while (right.options.length) {
  right.remove(0);
}

// Copy existing options
for (var i = 0, l = left.options.length; i < l; i++) {
  right.add(left.options[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: @Surya: I can't help you with that if you don't provide any information.